# Display data label always on first visible point

Tags: highcharts

On my highcharts chart I use

```
this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
      min: newDateValue,
    });
```

to set a new xAxis time range an "zoom" into the data.
I want to display a data label always on the first visible data point. How can I get the first point on xAxis update and render a data label there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `afterSetExtremes` event you can check `isInside` flag on the point and enable or disable the `dataLabel`:

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function() {
            var series = this.chart.series,
                pointFound,
                i = 0;

            series.forEach(function(s) {
                pointFound = false;

                s.points.forEach(function(p) {
                    if (p.isInside && !pointFound) {
                        p.update({
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        });
                        pointFound = true;
                    } else if (p.dataLabel) {
                        p.update({
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qv0bcr3t/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update